# Going from an installation profile to vanilla Drupal

Tags: updating, distributions

I currently am using the Acquia Drupal installation profile on a site, and I want to convert it to a vanilla Drupal install.  Other than cross referencing the modules that come with the profile, and making sure you download those from drupal.org and putting them into sites/all/modules, are there anymore steps that would need to be taken besides your regular update instructions?

Comment: One of the questions is *why* are you doing that? Installation profile is a set of modules + code that runs at the beginning. Now, if you will replicate everything on vanilla Drupal, you will effectively continue using profile, right? So what's your goal? Why can't you just continue using profile, but update modules you need updated?

Answer (score 1):

Once a Drupal site is installed, it doesn't really matter which installation profile you used. The only difference is that it's possible to use modules and themes that are located in the profiles folder. So in that sense you are running vanilla Drupal.

If you want to disable the possibility to use the modules from the profile you need to, once you have added the modules to sites/all, set the installation profile to "standard". The easiest way to that is to use drush:

```
$ drush vset install_profile standard
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying only modules doesn't help, but will closer. Installation profiles also run DB changes, so you need reproduce settings from code.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the module files from the installation profile to sites/all/modules *before* you run the installation. After the installation you could even delete the profile.

Comment: "before you run the **installation**"  ---do you mean before the **update**?

Comment: I think I missed the fact that you have a running site and not asking for fresh installation. I would try to find the path of the modules in the DB and change this with SQL to the standard path. But that's just a guess. Never tryed this myself.

Comment: You don't need to change the path of the modules in the database.  Remember, Drupal sees things in a overriding hierarchy type of way.  It first looks in /sites/MYSITE/modules, if nothing in there it next looks in /sites/all/modules, if nothing in there it next looks in profile modules.

Answer (score 0):

here are some modified steps from This article: http://davehall.com.au/blog/dave/2012/09/12/switching-installation-profiles-existing-drupal-sites  that worked for me.

```
$ drush vset -y install_profile my_profile
```

An alternative way of doing this is by directly manipulating the database. You can run the following SQL on your Drupal database to switch installation profiles:

```
UPDATE variable SET value = 'my_profile' WHERE name = 'install_profile';
-- Clear the cache using MySQL only syntax, when DB caching is used.
TRUNCATE cache;
```

Also you should:

```
echo "UPDATE system s SET schema_version = 0 WHERE s.name = 'my_profile'" | drush sqlc && drush cc all
```

Before you switch installation profiles, you should check that you have all the required modules enabled in your site. 
    drush en $(grep depedencies /path/to/my-site/profiles/my_profile/my_profile.info | sed -n 's/depedencies[]=(.*)/\1/p')